# unknown (amplifier?) board from ONKYO HT-R410 A/V Receiver

Tags: pcb, amplifier, audio

About a week ago, I scrapped an ONKYO receiver that was starting to die (it was around 20 years old and having some problems with audio quality) and among the internal boards and giant filter capacitors, I found a board with five identical circuits on it. I think they're amplifiers, because each one is labeled either L, R, C, LS, or RS for the different speakers. I could use some help determining if they're amplifiers, and if so how to connect and use them. If they aren't amplifiers, I'd like to know what they are.

[image: front of board (brown side)]

[image: back of board (green side)]

Comment: I googled the board part number ncaf-7866 and got this manual https://www.scribd.com/doc/284651479/Onkyo-TX-SR302 which has a similar looking board labelled as “driver amplifier pc board”

Comment: Could you upload the image of the specific page that shows the board (or better yet the whole document)? I have no experience with scribd and it seems to be a subscription-based service, so I could only see the first 3 pages.

Comment: They look like preamplifier stages, not power amplifiers.

Comment: they were close to, and probably connected to, a set of large NPN and PNP transistors on a massive heatsink, so those could be part of the amplifier section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "Driver Section" - all the requisite electronics to drive the high power part of the amplifier,. Complete schematics for the amplifier can be had for free without registration from
https://manualzz.com/doc/43969059/service-manual-model-ht-r410

I've snipped the schematic of this driver board from the above service manual "ONKYO SERVICE MANUAL AV Receiver Black and Silver models MODEL HT-R410"

[image: Service manual driver snip]

And also here's a single driver and power stage zoomed in to show how they would work together:
[image: service manual driver detail snip]
[image: Service manual power amp detail snip]

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about making an audio amplifier, and now I can use these two circuits with the components I got from the receiver to build one.